# React-Native wrapping a typed class into functional component for styling

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-generics

I am wrapping components into functional components in order to perform consistent styling. This works pretty good most of the time, but if the wrapped component has generics in their properties things get a little messy. Specifically I cant wrap my head around the `FlatList` component and how to define the `ItemT`.

```
  type Props<ItemT> = React.ComponentProps<typeof FlatList> & {
     theme: Theme
  }

  const MyFlatList = <ItemT extends {}>(props: Props<ItemT>) => {
     const { theme } = props

     return <FlatList {...props} contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: theme.colors.background }} />
  }

  export default withTheme(MyFlatList)
```

This basically matches what `react-native-paper` recommends here https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component.
While this compiles without errors the type information is lost, if I am using this component in my code.

```
   <MyFlatList
      data={items}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem(item)}
    />
```

The `item` in this case is of type `unknown` whereas in plain `FlatList` the type is properly derived. I guess the problem is `ItemT extends {}`, but I haven't found any other way to let the caller define the `ItemT`. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party but I had a similar issue today. During research I stumbled upon something that's called "Generic forwardRef" which helped me wrap and type react-native's FlatList component.

You can read more about it [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref/#option-1---wrapper-component)

Your item type should be inferred correctly, if you wrap your component like this:

```
interface MyFlatListProps<ItemT> extends FlatListProps<ItemT> {
    theme: Theme
}

function MyFlatList<ItemT>(props: MyFlatListProps<ItemT>) {
    const { theme } = props

    return <FlatList {...props} contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: theme.colors.background }} />
}
```

export default withTheme(MyFlatList)